# VSCode when clause context for a terminal opened with particular profile

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to create a keybinding which should open a new terminal with a profile only if there does not an already opened terminal with the same profile.

Consider the following keyboard mapping

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+alt+shift+c",
    "command": "workbench.action.terminal.newWithProfile",
    "args": {
    "profileName": "IPython"
}
```

What it does currently is that everytime I press `ctrl+alt+shift+c` it keeps opening new terminals with `IPython` profile, what I want is that it should create a new `IPython` terminal for the first time when I hit this key combination and the subsequent key presses should not create a new `IPython` terminal rather it should simply move my focus to the already opened terminal instance.

Is it possible to achieve this behavior somehow ?

I went through the docs [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/when-clause-contexts#available-context-keys)  but could not find any available context which can used in the when clause to perform this check.

Seems like there is no way to achieve as of now, so I submitted a [feature request](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/189602) for the same in vscode repo.

Comment: now that you've created your feature-request, I suggest you share it with your dev friends and colleagues who use VS Code and on [r/vscode](https://www.reddit.com/r/vscode) to ask people to give it a thumbs up so it can get added to the backlog. This part is a bit time sensitive (60 days).